# Generalization of Gradient Theorem for Vector Valued Functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, hessian-matrix

"The gradient theorem, also known as the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals, says that a line integral through a gradient field can be evaluated by evaluating the original scalar field at the endpoints of the curve." This is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem

My question is the following: Is there a generalization of gradient theorem for vector valued functions, namely:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n  $ be a continuously differentiable vector valued function and $\gamma$ be any curve from $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{b}$.

Then

$$
\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{J}[f] d\mathbf{r} = f(\mathbf{b}) - f(\mathbf{a})
$$

where $\mathbf{J}$ is the Jacobian.

If yes, is there a generalization of conservative vector field to matrices?

Comment: Yes, the formula you wrote is correct.  It's even true for functions $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ where $n$ and $k$ are different.  And sure, you could say that a $(k \times n)$ matrix of functions is "conservative" if it is the Jacobian matrix of a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$, but this concept / terminology is not common.  If $n = 3$, you probably want to say that the curl of a conservative matrix is some sort of zero "object" ... meaning that you first need to say what the curl of a matrix is, and in this setup, that means bringing in tensor fields.

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Thanks a lot Jesse, can you point me some references or keywords about this?

Comment: I've never actually seen your formula written down anywhere, but proving it is easy: Write out the left-hand side and use the $k = 1$ case on each component to get the right-hand side.  The highbrow way to think about gradients, curl, divergence, etc., is in terms of "differential forms."  In that framework, your generalization amounts to looking at "vector-valued differential forms" (the Wikipedia page is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form)